# Combining Records in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce

I have `Transaction` objects that are combined in a `Cart` object. Some `Transaction` objects `belong_to` `Products` and others `belong_to` `Services`. I want to combine similar `Transactions` when they are added to the cart (ie. update an existing record with new price and quantity information).

Here's what I currently have (untested):

```
def update_cart
  if current_cart.transactions.find(:conditions => [service_id = self.service_id])
    @utransaction = current_cart.transaction.find(:conditions => [service_id = self.service_id])
    @utransaction.price = @utransaction.price + self.price
    @utransaction.save
  elsif current_cart.transactions.find(:conditions => [product_id = self.product_id])
    @utransaction = current_cart.transactions.find(:conditions => [product_id = self.product_id])
    @utransaction.price = @utransaction.price + self.price
    @utransaction.quantity = @utransaction.quantity + self.quantity
    @utransaction.save
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

However, I feel that this is very bulky and there is probably a better way of doing it. So, before I go any further, is there any built-in or better ways of updating existing objects in this manner?

Thanks!

Comment: So a Transaction can belong_to a Product or belong_to a Service?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And, the reason Product and Service aren't combined into an STI is because they have fields that are too different and may be changed a lot over time. However, I'm planning on now combining them into a polymorphic association (as suggested by ardavis below), which should simplify it a bit. But, the question then is is the rest of this code in my example the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Transaction can belong_to a Product or belong_to a Service, then it sounds like a Polymorphic association is your best bet, and may make your existing problem much simpler.

Check out the [Railscast on Polymorphic Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).

I think you'll like it and learn a lot.

Comment: Okay, I just checked out this video and definitely think that polymorphic associations are the way to go (something I didn't do initially and will implement now, thanks and +1 for that!). But, how does that affect the code above? I still have to check whether it's a Product or Service and then update those variables in the same manner, right?

Comment: I'm going to have to let someone else give that one a go, :) Glad I could help some though.